# ElasticSearch - Bulk Indexing with refresh

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I need to index about 1000 documents as fast as possible. I decided to use bulk function that works about 10 times faster than my original solution. I need to make [refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/docs-refresh.html) right after indexing ends to make documents searchable. In other situation i would use refresh parameter ***'refresh' => true,*** but i cant make it work with bulk in PHP. I use [code from official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_indexing_documents.html#_bulk_indexing).

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $params['body'][] = [
        'index' => [
            '_index' => 'my_index',
            '_type' => 'my_type',
        ]
    ];

    $params['body'][] = [
        'my_field' => 'my_value',
        'second_field' => 'some more values'
    ];
}

$responses = $client->bulk($params);
```

What is the right way to use refresh in PHP bulk function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used fake update operation with refresh right after bulk

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'refresh',
    'id' => 'refresh',
    'refresh' => true,             // REFRESH
    'body' => []
];

$client->index($params);
```

This is not the best way to do it but the only that worked for me.

Comment: so instead of calling refresh everytime, it calls after all bulk data are indexed

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
$params['refresh'] = true;
```

**after** your loop and before bulk insert.

So eventually the code would be

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $params['body'][] = [
        'index' => [
            '_index' => 'my_index',
            '_type' => 'my_type',
        ]
    ];

    $params['body'][] = [
        'my_field' => 'my_value',
        'second_field' => 'some more values'
    ];
}

$params['refresh'] = true;
$responses = $client->bulk($params);
```